# Kerberos Service Principal not found in AD

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, kinit

I've got a strange problem with an Active Directory SPN Account.

This does not work:
kinit HTTP/my.host.com@MY.REALM

However, "setspn -l SA_MyUser" lists "HTTP/my.host.com" as registered service principal.
It has got to be a problem withthe AD account, but what could it be?

Comment: Can you share some more details please? Do you get an error for your kinit attempt? Have you taken a network trace to see if the request for the service ticket is going to the right KDC? Is the domain where the SA_MYUSER in MY.REALM? where are you doing the kinit from? Is it a member of the MY.REALM ?